# Different Post length validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Ok so there is no code here I would just like to get some feedback on how you would approach this issue.

I have a Book and I would like to give the user an option to create a short, medium or long book. This will create a integer, 0,1,2 which is then a constant and will define how long the posts can be in length:

I'm sitting here scratching my head, should I create multiple classes in the model for short,medium,long and then set the constants in there so that when the user selects 0 for example it is linked to class short < Book. I tried mapping this out on paper and confused myself even more.

Some help or feedback on how you'd approach this issue would be very useful.

EDIT: Thanks Sevencats, this is what I was thinking along the lines of. Quick question, how would I use the form builder collection select to define these values in Books.size?

I would need to pass a value through the form of 0,1,2 to the column size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply sounds like conditional validation to me.

If a Book has a property eg. `length` and length can be 0, 1, or 2, then when you add Posts to the book, the length of the posts get validated depending on the parent book's length.

Something like (this may not be like your exact example but close enough):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def short?
    length == 0
  end

  def long?
    length == 2
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book

  validates_length_of :content, less_than: 500, if: book.short?
  validates_length_of :content, less_than: 1000, if: book.long?
end
```

Comment: You could also add to the model def self.short; where length: 0 end. Doing that you can now get all short books by going Book.short.

Comment: a good idea and probably useful, but not really related to this question.

Comment: you gave a great answer and I wanted to complement it bro.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Quick side note, could you tell me how I'd get the information from the dropdown, I'm looking at the collection select or should I just put a hidden field to assign a value. I have a column in books called size.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: I wouldn't go by collection_select. I would do it this way:

Define a constant in your `Book` model:

```
SIZES = {0 => 'Small', 1 => 'Medium', 2 => 'Large'}
```

Now this hash is accessible like this from anywhere:

```
Book::SIZES
```

And:

```
Book::SIZES[1]
=> "Medium"
```

In the view, when you need a select, do:

```
form_builder.select :size, Book::SIZES.invert
```

The `invert` will make the values into keys and the keys into values, which is what the `select` method needs.

Come to think of it, you could even put this in the `Book` model:

```
SIZES = {SMALL=0 => 'Small', MEDIUM=1 => 'Medium', LARGE=2 => 'Large'}
```

Now you can go `Book::SMALL` and it gives you `0`.

From inside the `Book` model you wouldn't have to prefix `Book` to things, so you can freely use `MEDIUM` wherever you like, and go:

```
SIZES[ MEDIUM ]
# which is the same as:
SIZES[1]
```

and it gives you `"Medium"`.